# SQLAlchemy - Unable to reflect SQL view

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm getting the following error message when trying to reflect any of my SQL views:

```
sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/reflection.py", line 306, in _describe_to_create
    buffer.append(" ".join(line))
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, bytes found
```

I have tried using both the `autoload_with` and `autoload=True` options in my `select` query constructor to no avail.

I have the appropriate permissions on my view. My query is pretty simple:

```
company_country = Table('company_country', metadata, autoload_with=engine)
query = select(company_country.c.country)
return query
```

I've tried the `inspect` utility and it does not list my SQL view, nor does the reflecting all tables described below the views section on this page: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#reflecting-views

I'm using version SQLAlchemy->1.4.32, Python 3.x and mySQL 8.0.28 on Mac if that's any help

I should add that I can query my SQL views using the `text()` constructor but it would be far more preferable to use `select()` if possible.

Any tips appreciated

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/t5BCmGGK) works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks. I'm guessing one isn't required to create views via SQLA to query them, right?

Comment: That is correct. The example code would work just as well if `my_table` and `my_view` already existed and didn't have to create them.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the mysql-connector client for interop with other code, but after switching to the mysqlclient, I was able to reflect the views.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqldb